# Finding connected device using Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Suppose `n` number of device are connected in a Firebase server. And one of them is disconnected (suppose its battery charge is run out), how I notify the remaining `n-1` device that `n-th` device is disconnected. Is there any service provided by Firebase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll basically need to build a presence system using firebase. Check this for more about how to build one : [Firebase Presence](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/06/how-to-build-presence-system.html)

Once you have that in place, then on each device, you can listen for any changes in the presence node in firebase which will notify all the other connected device when one device goes offline or comes online.